# Run a job in a raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, jobs

I have written some simple python scripts and I would like to run them on my raspberry pi even when I am not logged in. So far, I can log in to the machine via ssh and run the script without a problem. As soon as I have to disconnect the ssh session, I notice that the script breaks or stops. Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to keep the script running after the end of the ssh connection.

Here is the system I am using: `Raspberry pi 3B+ with ubuntu 22.04 LTS`, and here is how I run my script:

```
ssh xx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cd myapp/
python3 runapp.py
```

Comment: _run them - - even when I am not logged in_ Do you mean run them at a certain time (`man crontab`) or just leave them running when you log out (`python3 runapp.py &`)?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding it properly, but I don't now how to cut the ssh while the python script is running. What I have tried is to kill the ssh session from the home computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nohup` to stop hangup signals affecting your process. Here are three different ways of doing it.

---

This is a *"single shot"* command, I mean you type it all in one go:

```
ssh SOMEHOST "cd SOMEWHERE && nohup python3 SOMESCRIPT &"
```

---

Or here, you log in, change directory and get a new prompt in the remote host, run some commands and then, at some point, exit the `ssh` session:

```
ssh SOMEHOST
cd SOMEWHERE
nohup python SOMESCRIPT &
exit
```

---

Or, this is another *"single shot"* where you won't get another prompt till you type `EOF`

```
ssh SOMEHOST <<EOF
cd SOMEWHERE
nohup python SOMESCRIPT &
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a way to keep the script running after the end of the ssh connection.

Just run it in the background.

```
python3 runapp.py &
```

You could store the logs to system log.

```
python3 runapp.py | logger &
```

You could learn about `screen` and `tmux` virtual terminals, so that you can view the logs later. You could start a `tmux` session, run the command inside and detach the session.

You could setup a systemd service file with the program, and run is "as a service".

Comment: I have just tried and seems to work. However, when I try to exit the ssh session, this is what I see: 

There are still jobs active:

   PID  Command
  4151  python3 runapp.py | logger &

A second attempt to exit will terminate them.
Use 'disown PID' to remove jobs from the list without terminating them.

Answer (score 0):

If atd is running you can use `at` to schedule commands to be executed at a particular time.

Examples:

```
$ echo "python3 /path/to/runapp.py"|at 11:00
job 10 at Fri Jun  3 11:00:00 2022

$ echo "python3 /path/to/runapp.py" | at now
job 11 at Thu Jun  2 19:57:00 2022

# after minutes/hours/days/....
$ echo "python3 /path/to/runapp.py" | at now +5 minutes
$ echo "python3 /path/to/runapp.py" | at now +2 hours


$ ssh user@host "echo 'python3 /path/to/runapp.py'| at now"
```

Jobs created with `at` are executed only once.